# cakephp place files outside webroot

Tags: file, cakephp

I would like to know if it's possible with CakePHP to place files (pdf for example) outside the webroot directory WITHOUT using Media Views (I've tried with it and it only works when you want to make files available for **download**, but not if you want to just link those files for something else, like from a Flash application for example).

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

You can place files anywhere you want, provided you have the write permission, just use regular PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

You place files in webroot when you want these files accessible for direct download.

Edit: I think I know what you meant: If you wan it available for Flash application (or download, or anything outside), put it in the webroot. Why do you not want to put them in the webroot anyway?

Edit: Use the Media View, and you'll need a way to check if the request is originated from the flash player or not to allow the file to be sent.

Comment: could you give me an example? Say there's a folder called **files** inside my **app** folder, at the same level of **webroot**. How would I link a file called **song.mp3** inside that folder from a view?

Comment: well the main reason is because I want to play some mp3 files from a flash player, without letting the users download them. The thing is that the player I'm using (which I can't change) receives the path of the song as a parameter using **flashVars** in the _embed_ tag, so I'm trying to place the files somewhere else so users can't see their path with just a _view source_ click...

Comment: they don't need to view source. There's a Firefox addon that can capture your mp3 easily. If you want them not be able to download the file, I advise to find another way (and not using that flash player). And it's pretty complicated to get that working decently though.

Comment: yeah, I know that they can find ways to download them even without knowing the path, but it's not as easy as seeing the path on the HTML... so basically there's no way to do what I want in CakePHP? I'm sure there has to be a way...

Comment: I tried with Media Views an couldn't make it work... how could I check if the request is originated from a flash movie?